# '一三一四五二零' I need someone to confirm the meaning of this number sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

1314520 (一三一四五二零) is a thing that my mother used to say to me. I asked her what those numbers meant and she told me to read them out loud. I think it means 'Love you forever' but I need someone to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 一三一四五二零 yì sān yí sì wǔ èr líng

in Mandarin sounds close to

> 一生一世我愛你 yì shēng yí shì wǒ ài nǐ

which means 'I love you for the whole of my life'.

Comment: 有隻廣東歌叫「禪院鐘聲」俾人用數字代替歌詞都可以完全對到旋律. 證明十個數字包含大量不同聲調同尾音